# Nil access error when following LevelHelper tutorial

Tags: sdk, coronasdk, levelhelper

I started to make a game on Corona SDK with the help of Level Helper and Sprite Helper. I have used [this video tutorial](http://youtu.be/MHrhrg2Qi7M) and all things have been done exactly like in the video, but I have this error. I don't understand why.

```
File: ...DK Projects/Runner/LevelHelper/LevelHelperLoader.lua  
Line: 743

stack traceback:  
    [C]: ?  
    ...DK Projects/Runner/LevelHelper/LevelHelperLoader.lua:743: in function 'createAllNodes'  
    ...DK Projects/Runner/LevelHelper/LevelHelperLoader.lua:150: in function 'instantiateObjects'  
    ...slav/Documents/Corona SDK Projects/Runner/level1.lua:34: in function <...slav/Documents/Corona SDK Projects/Runner/level1.lua:29>  
    ?: in function 'dispatchEvent'  
    ?: in function 'gotoScene'  
    ...heslav/Documents/Corona SDK Projects/Runner/menu.lua:22: in function '_onRelease'  
    ?: in function '?'  
    ?: in function <?:371>  
    ?: in function <?:218> 

Attempt to index field 'lhNodes' (a nil value)
```

Can you please tell me what I've done incorrectly?

Comment: Do you have an object named 'lhNodes' in your project? Then add 'local lhNodes' at the top of your code and make the object a available throughout the scene. Make sure all your scene names, image names and image path are correct. And if you provide further code, it will be helpful to identify the correct problem...

Comment: Please include the your code where the error occurs

Answer (score 0):

This usually means that a SpriteHelper document is missing from your project or your LevelHelper API is outdated and was not generated using LevelHelper.

Please use www.gamedevhelper.com forum for LevelHelper related questions where I get notified and can reply instantly.